# msbuild Wix toolset 3.7 source code in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, wix, wix3.7

I am trying to manually build the wix toolset 3.7 on a windows 8 machine that has VS2012 installed, but I keep on running into the following error:

*error WIXBUILD002: Error the "Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Frame 4" or "Visual Studio 2012" must be installer.*

According to the wix documentation  http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixdev/building_wix.html

it should work when the command: msbuild /p:VisualStudioVersion="11.0" is used.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

By changing the `<PlatformSdkInstallPath>` in the WixBuild.props file from 8.0 to 8.0A WIXBUILD002 error is solved. But, now I am get about 72 errors, mostly related to the MSBUILD

> ```
> error MSB8020: The build tools for Visual Studio 2010
> (Platform Toolset = 'v100') cannot be found. To build
> using the v100 build tools, either click the project
> menu or right-click on the solution, and then select
> "Update VC++ Projects..."
> ```

Comment: Can you please check the value of your registry entry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0` and check whether this value path actually exists with the Windows SDK files? If so I think I can get more clarity on this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't have HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0, but I do have HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A. Within that registry, The InstallationFolder is set to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A, ProductName is set to Microsoft .Net Framework 4.5 SDK, and ProductVersion is set to 8.0.50727. Thanks again!

Comment: By the way, there are 3 more sub-folders under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A, these are: WinSDK-NetFx35Tools, WinSDK-NetFx35Tools-x64 and WinSDK-NetFx35Tools-x86.

Answer (score 1):

As I went through the WIX build targets, the definition for `Error WIXBUILD002` is in the file `\tools\WixBuild.Tools.targets`. That happens if a file path as per the property `PlatformSdkBinPath` is not present or if the property is having empty value. The value of `PlatformSdkBinPath` is set in the file `\tools\WixBuild.props` as `$(PlatformSdkInstallPath)bin\` and `PlatformSdkInstallPath` in turn is having its value read from registry entry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0`. Apparently in your machine there is no registry entry like that and instead it is `v8.0A`.

The issue is that, WIX MSBuild is not able to locate Windows SDK in your machine. Most probably it can be bug in WIX source as well.

So, basically the solution is that to change the registry key path (only `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0`) in the files `\tools\WixBuild.props` (`PlatformSdkInstallPath` property) and `\tools\OneTimeWixBuildInitialization.proj` (`NetfxSdkInstallPath` property) to end with `v8.0A` instead of current `v8.0` and to have a try on MSBuild.

**EDIT:**

To address this issue of:

> MSB8020: The build tools for Visual Studio 2010 (Platform Toolset =
>   'v100') cannot be found. To build using the v100 build tools, either
>   click the project menu or right-click on the solution, and then select
>   "Update VC++ Projects..."

you can refer to the solution available for this MSDN post I think. The solution here basically is to install [Windows Driver Kit 8](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=324284).

**Note:** I feel like your VS 2012 installation has some basic issues or else the flavor\version of VS 2012 you are using is missing a lot of things.

Comment: Hi RinoTom, Thank you very much for the prompt reply. I edited the PlatformSdkInstallPath to from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\...\8.0 to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\...\8.0A, and it was still giving me the same error. From the hints that you provided, I found that <PlatformSdkIncludePath> is also needed (which I didn't have), so I end up copying the directories ./include and ./lib from the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A to the C:\Program Files (x86)\...\v8.0A folder.

Comment: Ran the MSBUILD and got this "error:MSB8020 The builds tools for Visual Studio 2010 (Plateform Toolset='v100') cannot be found." Thank again for your help.

Comment: Copying the files from v7.1A fodler to v8.0A may not work. Probably that is the reason you are getting error:MSB8020 now. If you don't have v8.0A folder I think, your Windows SDK is not installed properly with Visual Studio 2012 installation. Can you download [Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30668) and install the same and try this. I suppose that should create this v8.0A folder as well.

Comment: Thanks RinoTom for the tip. I reinstalled the VS 2012 SDK and unfortunately in my V8.0A folder, it only contains ./bin and ./Bootstrapper directory. The WixBuild.Tools.targets requires that $(PlatformSdkIncludePath) to exist, which in this case will cause the same "WIXBUILD002" error. So my quandary is that I need ./include directory in my C:\Program Files (x86)\...\v8.0A folder to get pass the "WIXBUILD002" error and VS 2012 SDK doesn't install it. If I copy the .\include directory from V7.1A (or any other) directory, I get the MSBUILD error. Thank you very much once again.

Comment: Another note that I forgot to mention is that I couldn't find the "NetfxSdkInstallPath" property in the OneTimeWixBuildInitialization.proj file. That's probably not related to the problem that I am experiencing, but I can't be certain. Thank you!

Comment: May I know from where Wix 3.7 code was downloaded by you so that I can refer the same. I downloaded the same from http://wix.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest by selecting 'wix37' in 'Browsing changes in' dropdown and that code doesn't have an option to build using VS2012. I mean it has reference only to SDK v7.0A. Till now I was referring to the code downloaded by selecting 'master ' in the same link (i.e., the latest WIX code). That is why I got "NetfxSdkInstallPath" property. So, no need to worry about that property. We need only "PlatformSdkInstallPath" property.

Comment: Even another copy of Wix 3.7 source I got from http://wix.codeplex.com/releases/view/99514 as well can be built using only v7.0A. One more thing I tried in between is that, I tried installing [Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/apps/hh852363) and I am able to get \Include and \Lib folders. So, probably that can also be a solution. But, not sure.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for your replies. I downloaded wix's source from http://wix.codeplex.com/releases/view/99514, which happens to be the "Downloads" tab. As for the Windows SDK, I download 3 copies of Windows SDK for windows and tried install, uninstall and repair multiple times with no luck (no ./include and ./lib folders). :) I'll try again today (keeping my fingers cross). By the way, I also downloaded wix source codes from the link that your provided in your response. Hopefully, I'll have better luck with this one. Thank you so very much for your help.

Comment: I tried this Windows SDK in deployment in a machine without Visual Studio and all and it deploys all these files in C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0 and sets that folder to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0 @ InstallationFolder. So, I thought since you already have VS 2012 and  registry entry is set, this SDK installation will put the content to your current folder of C:\Program Files (x86)\...\v8.0A. As right now I don't have an env with VS 2012, if you can give a day's time I can try the same on an env with VS 2012 and post about the same.

Comment: The code you downloaded earlier from http://wix.codeplex.com/releases/view/99514 cannot be built using VS 2012 and allied things I suppose, it shows registry reference to v7.0A and not any for v8.0\v8.0A. The code available from  http://wix.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest can built with VS 2012 (v8.0/v8.0A), I think since it has those registry reference, but it may not be picture perfect code as this is the latest and unreleased code.

Comment: In parallel you can try contacting [Rob Mensching](http://www.codeplex.com/site/users/view/robmen) through CodePlex as well regarding this. He is available in [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/users/23852/rob-mensching) as well. He leads the WIX toolset development.

Comment: Thank you so very much. I am trying to reinstall the Windows SDK again and see whether it'll make any difference this time. I'll install it with my fingers cross the whole time.

Comment: Hi RinoTom, I forgot to ask a simple question. When you make a build of the wix source, do you encounter any errors? For me, initially, I encountered 142 errors (everything failed), before I changed the <PlatformSdkInstallPath> in the WixBuild.props file from 8.0 to 8.0A. now I am get about 72 errors, mostly related to the MSBUILD eroor MSB8020: The build tools for Visual Studio 2010 (Platform Toolset = 'v100') cannot be found. To build using the v100 build tools, either click the project menu or right-click on the solution, and then select "Update VC++ Projects..." Thank you so so much!

Comment: Which flavor of VS 2012 you are using like Express, Premium, Ultimate, etc.?

Comment: Thanks a million RinoTom, I have the Ultimate edition. By the way, I have reinstalled the Windows SDK and I still don't see the ./include folder in my C:\Program Files(x86)\...\8.0A folder. In addition, I forgot to mentioned that when I got those MSBuild errors, I was able to get it partially build. Hence the number of errors went from 142 to 72. All the Extension folders were created but they were empty. I.E. (WixBalExtension, WixNetfxExtension,... etc). I have created a log file with the MSbuild parameter, so I'll look it over later. Hopefully, I'll find something. Many Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old post, but in case anyone new runs into this, this happened to me trying to build the WiX 3.14 burn solution and I fixed it by installing Windows SDK 10.0.17134.0, and .NET Framework 4. I'm using Visual Studio 2017.